# How find this the expected number of games played, if A won $n$ consecutive games?

Tags: probability

**Question 1:**

> A and B two people play a game, where the odds of winning for one per game is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.
>   If someone first win $n$ games consecutive,then the games end.Find this expect with the total number of games.

a few days ago. I have solve this simaler following  problem

**Question 2:**

> A and B play a game, where the odds of winning for one per game is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. For what number of games would A expect to win n games.

I have solve it and this relsut is $$E(X)=n^2$$

But I found if $A$ win $n$ games consecutive,and fell this case is very ugly.so can you help me?

In comment I have add chinese with this question

Comment: Lacking any information about the distribution of the number of games they played, I don't think this is problem is well-defined. (e.g. the result would depend on if we know it's more likely that they played less or more games, or that $A$ throws a tantrum if they lose, etc. that affects the result and there's no "natural" distribution to choose in the absence of other information) The best interpretation is probably "For what number of games would $A$ expect to win $n$ games consecutive?"

Comment: I still can't understand the question. Perhaps you could include the solution to the similar problem, so that we can understand what you mean.

Comment: An infinite number of games.

Comment: A和B两人玩游戏，每人每局胜的概率为1/2.若有一个人连续赢n局。问游戏总局数的期望是多少

Comment: "for what number of games would A expect to win" -**exactly** n games?  or **at least** n games?  For your second question if it should be at least n games, would it not be $2n$?  Furthermore, "expect to" $\Rightarrow P($wins [at least] n games$)\geq 50\%$?

Comment: hello, 恰好连续赢n  局就结束

Comment: To add a version of the question in Chinese, add it to the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_k$ denote the number of games that the player who won game $k$ managed to win in succession at the times preceding $k$. Then $(g_k)$ is a Markov chain starting from $0$ with transitions $0\to1$ with probability $1$ and, for every $k\geqslant1$, $k\to k+1$  with probability $\frac12$ and $k\to1$ with probability $\frac12$. 
The question seems to ask to compute $E(t_n)$ for every $n\geqslant1$, where $t_n=\inf\{k\mid g_k=n\}$.

Thus, $t_1=1$ and, for every $k\geqslant1$, the Markov property at time $t_n$ yields $$E(t_{n+1})=E(t_n)+\tfrac12\cdot1+\tfrac12\cdot(1+E_1(t_{n+1})),$$ where $E_1(t_{n+1})$ denotes the time to reach $n+1$ starting from $1$, thus $E(t_{n+1})=1+E_1(t_{n+1})$. 
Thus, $E(t_{n+1})=2E(t_n)+1$, that is, $E(t_{n+1})+1=2\cdot(E(t_n)+1)$, and $E(t_1)=1$ hence, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$E(t_n)=2^{n+1}-2.$$